# bot framework - luis entity score is not available in luis v3.0

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am working with bot framework adaptive dialog. I have an issue in getting luis entity score while calling luis end point.
I have migrated my luis to v3.0. Is there any property available to get the luis entity score in endpoint?
I have given subscription key,query,verbose and show all intents property as the query strings in the endpoint. did i missed to set any property in the luis endpoint?

I really appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In V3, you can use the verbose flag to return entity metadata.
Please follow the below doc for prediction endpoint changes in v3 API.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-migration-api-v3

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/luis-concept-intent#return-all-intents-scores

[image]